# Altium Connections

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

In Altium, does a multilayer Pad with the same net as a plane (internal ground plane in this case) automatically connect to that plane, or is a separate via required?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the connection is automatically added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I can confirm that it does connect automatically, you don't need a separate via.